# What does "network: Cache entry not found [url: ...]" mean exactly?

Tags: java, caching, networking, access-control, worldwind

**Shortly**

I cannot figure out what is the common reason of `network: Cache entry not found [url: ...]` message's appearence in Java console during applet running in web browser. I've get that this one can appear when performing with `java.net.URLConnection` (requesting some data from the Internet) but still don't know about its any possible reasons to look for to investigate my particular problem. So my questions are: **what are possible reasons of this message and can this affect application's normal run? Finally, what is the cache and can I control it somehow?**

**In detail**

It will be too difficult and unnecessary to post big code snippets so I'll try to describe the problem as simplier as possible.

I am building an applet based on [NASA WorldWind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) and facing a very strange behavior when requesting tiled image layers calling corresponding applet's method from JavaScript. Tiled image layer is a layer that can overlay 3D Earth and consisting of sets of fixed-size pictures (tiles) which are to be requested separately during layer's loading (suppose, layer is something like a puzzle of tiles :). That's why each tile's request has its own thread.

Initially I had an [AccessControllerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/AccessControlException.html) due to each tile request thread had no permissions to make crossdomain requests and read/save load results to local file cache. This problem has been solved by wrapping tile request's actual code by

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        // Requesting tile and performing with the result...
        // ...
    }
});
```

As the result, I see that tiles are loaded and stored in local file cache directory. But I still don't see the layer on the Earth. The fact is that I get the following network messages in Java console:

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://caches.scanex.ru/getTile.cgi?T=BMNG-01-2004&L=0&X=4&Y=1, version: null]
network: Connecting http://caches.scanex.ru/getTile.cgi?T=BMNG-01-2004&L=0&X=4&Y=1 with proxy=HTTP @ /192.168.4.10:8080
```

I was able to find a place in the code when these messages appear - when getting HTTP response code:

```
HttpURLConnection htpc = (HttpURLConnection)fconnection;
responseCode = htpc.getResponseCode();
```

Then, I found out that `java.net.URL` instance provided for `URLConnection` and other preparations are also made in another thread. To be precise, tile's download goes through the following threads' chain where each child thread is represented by [java.util.concurrent.FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html):

`Layer's rendering thread` >> `Tile request task where URL is to be prepared basing on existing local cache data` >> `Reading tile contents and handling the result (storing in local cache if it's required` (it's where above network messages occur).

Finally, I granted privileges for all these threads with `AccessController.doPrivileged(...)` construction, and I can see the desired result - tiled image layers are overlayed. But I'm still confused by `Cache entry not found` messages 'cause they are left in Java console and appear for each requested tile. That's why I want to know:  **is such behavior normal, and what do these messages actually mean?**

P.S. For interested people - http://caches.scanex.ru doesn't work from outside at the moment.

Comment: Can you show some examples from a real log?

Comment: What do you mean? Examples of these network messages? All I can see in Java console when requesting tiles is a couple of lines per one request (no any exceptions). The former is `Cache entry not found`, the latter is `Connecting http://...`. You can see them fully above in my question's post.

Comment: Since http://caches.scanex.ru/ is not accessable from outside world for some reasons now, I can give a request to alternative accessable server: `network: Cache entry not found [url: http://91.208.39.131/getTile.cgi?T=MEM_12697_120228060152n00_tiles&L=0&X=2&Y=0, version: null]`, 
`network: Connecting http://91.208.39.131/getTile.cgi?T=MEM_12697_120228060152n00_tiles&L=0&X=2&Y=0 with proxy=HTTP @ /192.168.4.10:8080`

Comment: The above request returns 404 error code meaning that requested tile doesn't exist. Unfortunatelly, I get the similar message when request existing tile: `network: Cache entry not found [url: http://91.208.39.131/getTile.cgi?T=hrpt_noaa18_20120228_0015_34902_tiles&L=0&X=0&Y=0, version: null]`,
`network: Connecting http://91.208.39.131/getTile.cgi?T=hrpt_noaa18_20120228_0015_34902_tiles&L=0&X=0&Y=0 with proxy=HTTP @ /192.168.4.10:8080 /192.168.4.10:8080`

Comment: Here the clean link to existing tile: http://91.208.39.131/getTile.cgi?T=hrpt_noaa18_20120228_0015_34902_tiles&L=0&X=0&Y=0

Comment: You may be better off creating a small self contained exams

Comment: Example and then reposting your question. There is a lot of extraneous detail in the current question. And or you could search the sun source code for this message and see what it's doing . Good luck either way!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It would be too difficult to create a separate example of applet to demonstate the issue so I will be happy if I get the common possible reasons of these network messages. Looking at Sun's source code seems the better way to go. Thank you again.